# Rear camera not working

Tags: camera

My phone is an HTC Desire 816G dual sim and it's not rooted. My rear camera doesn't work. I dropped my phone on the carpet. Since then, it stopped working. Whenever I open any camera app, it shows the front camera and doesn't have the option to switch the camera to the rear. Even the flashlight app won't work.

Tried another camera app, tried to clear the cache, and rebooted the phone several times, but no luck. I read in some posts that the issue is with hardware and even resetting the phone won't work.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite obvious now that you should go consult repairs. Quite possibly it's only the camera module connector that broke loose, so a quick disassembly might just do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and after a month-long research, I now realize it was my secondary camera's cable that was disconnected.
But now I am able to use the flashlight function normally when I have determined that my damaged secondary camera is the root cause of my inability to turn on the camera.
And this was when this problem first started, the flashlight would not turn on.
Thank you for providing a similar experience, which helps me determine the probability of the cause of the problem.